# How to get ifelse() throwing data frames?

Tags: r, if-statement

Why won't these `ifelse()`s don't throw data frames (or matrices)?

```
x <- data.frame(a=1000, b=100)
> x
     a   b
1 1000 100

> ifelse(x[, 2] >= 8, x, NA)
[[1]]
[1] 1000

> ifelse(x[, 2] >= 8, x[1:2], NA)
[[1]]
[1] 1000

> ifelse(x[, 2] >= 8, cbind(x[[1]], x[[2]]), NA)
[1] 1000
```

The second column is always missing. How to get this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From its help file:

> ifelse returns a value with the **same shape as test** which is filled
>   with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the
>   element of test is TRUE or FALSE.

So it does actually return a dataframe if the input is a dataframe:

```
ifelse(x[, 1, drop = FALSE] > 0, 10, NA)
```

But in your case it is easier to use

```
if (test) x else NA
```

Comment: Thanks, with your hint I got what I want with `t(ifelse(x[x[ ,2] >= 2, ], x, NA))`.

Comment: Great that it works. I am curious why you want to use `ifelse`. The help file also actually says that the `if (test) else` construction is more efficient with a single test.

Comment: Because I want an output depending on a condition.

Answer (score 3):

Below quoted lines about return value from `ifelse` are very important (taken from `help`) in order to understand behavior of `ifelse`

> Value
>
> A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and
>   "class") as test and data values from the values of yes or no.
>
> Details
>
> If yes or no are too short, their elements are recycled.

In summary it suggests that for each `row` and `column` in test section of the corresponding data values will be returned for *yes* and *no*.

Lets take few examples to understand it.

> ```
> x <- data.frame(a=1000, b=100)
>
>
> ifelse(x[, 2] >= 8, x, NA)
> # Test : 1 row and 1 col. Hence return is x[1]
> # [[1]]
> #[1] 1000
>
> ifelse(x[, 2] >= 8, x[,2], NA)
> # Test : 1 row and 1 col. Hence return is x[,2][1]
> #[1] 100
>
> ifelse(x >= 8, x, NA)
> # Test : 1 row and 2 cols. Hence return is x[1,1] and x[1,1]
> # [[1]]
> # [1] 1000
> # 
> # [[2]]
> # [1] 100
>
> ifelse(x >= 8, 4, NA)
> # Test : 1 row and 2 cols. Values are recycled. 4 & 4 for corresponding row/col
> #    a b
> #[1,] 4 4 
>
> #Change x to 2x2
> x <- data.frame(a=1000:1001, b=100:101)
> ifelse(x >= 8, 4, NA)
> # Test : 2 row and 2 cols. Result will be 2 x 2 
> #     a b
> #[1,] 4 4
> #[2,] 4 4
> ```

Now, what option does one have to handle such problem?

Certainly one can use `if` as suggested by @Jordi. But just be careful that `if` is not vectorised. Hence test condition is applied only on `1st` element when `vector` is used in test condition. To handle those situations, functions like `any` or `all` comes very handy and make it possible to to use `vector` as part of test condition in `if`.